# How do I generate the | (vertical bar or pipe) symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

How can I generate the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|` in LaTeX?

Comment: You can use \vert

Comment: These days this would be on-topic over at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
...

\(|\)
```

Answer (score 13):

According to `texdoc symbols`:

`\mvert` and `\mid` are identical and produce a relation. `\vert` is a synonym for | and both produce the same symbol, but should be used in the context of an ordinal, and should be used as an operator, not as a delimiter (p54, bottom). `\divides` once again produces the same symbol but should be used as a binary “divides” operator.

`\lvert` and `\rvert` are left and right delimiters, respectively.

I included all of these different options for the | symbol because I am unsure of exactly what you need to do with it. However, any of these methods work - pick the one best for whatever math you're working on. Derivatives will work different then absolute value, etc.

If you get the error: `error: Undefined control sequence`, try importing `amsmath`